# Is this crystal layout OK?

Tags: pcb-design, emc, layout, crystal, emi-filtering

I have a 2 layer board where I have a crystal running at (16.3840 MHz 18 pF). This crystal is used in a component that has internal caps.

Does this layout look OK? Or should change anything? On bottom I just connect with normal ground plane. All the vias in image is for GND.

The unconnected track I put there as "fence" or guard ring (guard ring made the correct way?).

Maybe this is not high speed enough to create problems anyway. But I thought I would do it the correct way to learn how it should be done.

This is for a product that should pass EMC tests. At least that is my hope.

[image: CRYSTAL]

Comment: I would not include that non-connected track. Having GND around the crystal with a few vias should be sufficient. Ensure that your vias are spaced far enough apart that the fabricator will be OK with it. Evenly spaced 0.8 to 1.0 mm apart (including above `NetU2_21`) would be my approach.

Comment: Get rid of the non-connected track - it is an antenna just like your stub in the top fill. Don’t do a top fill unless you tie it to the ground plane with lots of vias. Open ended tracks are antennas.

Comment: Have you read any application notes about crystal layout design? Most likely your MCU manufacturer, whichever it is as you don't mention, has such an appnote. Sometimes the ground plane under the crystal should be a separate island from the main ground fill, so that no other currents can flow under and near the crystal. Although you rarely see that done.